# How can I learn to develop programs in Objective-C without a Mac?

Tags: objective-c, ide

Does a cloud IDE or another tool exist to develop and compile programs using Objective-C?

Comment: Have a look at [GNUstep](http://www.gnustep.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) has an Objective-C compiler.  However, the really interesting part of Objective-C is found in the Frameworks.  Apple uses Cocoa which is a updated revision (more or less) of the old NextStep frameworks. There is a GNU clone called GNUStep that works fairly well, but has a steep learning curve.  There is also a project on SourceForge called libFoundation which only provides some core objects and frameworks saves GUI frameworks.  You should be able to install a gcc/GNUStep or gcc/libFoundation on most linux distributions so you can start playing with Objective-C without having to pay for a mac.

GNUStep: http://www.gnustep.org/

libFoundation: http://sourceforge.net/projects/libfoundation/

Comment: To get the closest compatibility with OS X, you'll want to use GNUStep with LLVM Clang instead of GCC.

Answer (score 3):

Well if you just want to learn Objective-C you can use GNUSTEP:

http://www.gnustep.org/resources/ObjCFun.html

However if you want to develop Mac or iOS apps, buying a Mac is your best option.  I recommend buying a Mac Mini as XenElement stated.  You can use Monotouch, however you will use C# instead of Objective-C:

http://xamarin.com/monotouch